# Для чего нужно делать close source branch в bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

> Для чего нужно делать close source branch в bitbucket?

a) Что происходит с веткой если сделать `close source branch`?

b) И что будет если не сделать `close source branch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае `Закрыть` значит `Удалить`.

1. Если выбрать эту опцию, то ветка будет удалена в репозитории на сервере. После этого она может остаться только в виде локальной копии у вас на компьютере. Если вдруг надо всё отменить, то это можно сделать либо на сервере, отменив удаление ветки, либо запушив её заново из локальной копии.
2. Если не выбирать эту опцию, то ветка останется на месте. Так лучше не делать, т.к. в итоге в репозитории будут десятки и сотни веток и разобраться в них будет крайне сложно.

При этом при удалении ветки информация о ней не теряется. Вы всегда сможете посмотреть какие коммиты были в удалённой ветке и как она называлась.

Comment: Юрий спасибо большое за ответ!